# Can I use my ACER ASPIRE 421 ZQ1's ram to my DELL inspiron 14r 5421?

Tags: laptop, memory, acer-aspire

I have this Acer laptop which motherboard has gone due to thunder surge. So it's basically gone , but I also have a dell laptop and I was wondering if I could use the ram of the ACER laptop in my DELL one as DELL has another slot for RAM. Here are the details I could find in google about the ram's.

```
ACER:
   Chipset :AMD A68M
   RAM 4 GB
   Max Supported Size 8 GB
   Technology DDR3 SDRAM
   Form Factor SO-DIMM 204-pin
   Slots Qty 2

Dell:
    Chipset: Mobile Intel HM76 Express Chipset
    RAM Size    Up to 8GB
    RAM Type    1600Mhz DDR3
    RAM Slots   2
```

Also
Is there any way my motherboard would get burnt if I install these two rams together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RAM would be compatible, but there is a possibility it was damaged. I wouldn't expect it to cause any damage to the other machine, but I wouldn't want to guarantee that.

Personally I would try it and run a full MemTest across it once installed. As said though, I can't make you any guarantee of what it would do to your other machine.

Comment: Thank you , I think I should take a leap of faith then ... As it is compatible .... Hope it works ... By the can you tell the odds of damaging the machine , just for my peace of mind

Comment: Not exactly...! But I'd expect that if something has blown in the RAM, it would simply fail POST and not boot, replacing it with the old RAM restoring it. I've certainly never seen a RAM stick destroy a computer before.

Comment: Well , I am posting this after adding the RAM , I did a memtest for 30 minutes(Don't have enough patience) with no error .. Thank you ...

Comment: Glad to hear it, shame about the other machine but enjoy the memory boost..!